# SQL - "Save results as CSV" - use comma instead of Semi-Colon

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2008-express

Hey, i need to export a query result to a CSV, but i get a semi-colon as a delimiter.
I went to:

```
Tools - Options - Query Results - SQL Server - Results to Text
```

and set

```
Output format: Custom delimiter  
Custom delimiter: ,
```

and i still get the semicolon. when i return to the options, the original configuration is set.

I'm using MS SQL Management Studio 2008.

Thanx for the help

Comment: Why aren't you using "Output format: Comma delimited"? Does this not appear in Express Edition or something?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This one of the options that needs you to close that query window and open a new one before it takes effect.